# Imgur's "old, unused, and inactive content"

Tags: discussion, images, dead-links

Imgur plans to change its Terms of Service on May 15, 2023. Part of this will be the removal of "old, unused, and inactive content".

Many of the images on Stack Exchange have imgur links. What will happen to those?

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388556/imgur-tos-change-on-may-15th-2023-could-cause-the-loss-of-thousands-of-stack-exc) for discussion on global meta. Short answer: if it's uploaded via the stackexchange upload image function, it's fine, if not, there could be issues.

Comment: We have [$1970$ generic  imgur images](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3ai.imgur.com&searchOn=3) subject to this (i.e. which don't don't use SE's corporate stack interface `stack.imgur.com`). Possibly others too if there are other urls used besides `i.imgur.com`.